# Why there is a cow in Walter Bishop's Lab?

Tags: fringe

I started Fringe at season 2 and I noticed a cow in Walter Bishop's Lab.

Considering the hassle of keeping a cow in a lab, notably the odour that should be awful, is there any purpose of keeping it? 
Is there any back-story about it? 
Does it even have a name?

Comment: Why would you start with season 2?

Comment: The real question is, why WOULDN'T you have a have a cow in a lab? Who doesn't like fresh milk, laced with unmetabolized excess hallucinogens, in their coffee?

Comment: @zoe [Keen](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1027/keen) [recommended me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2345829#2345829) to do so : `I'd expect most people would like the show if they read wikipedia summaries for s1 then started at s2.`

Comment: @DavRob60 Season 1 introduces too much backstory to skip.  It's not part of the monster-of-the-week plot of each episode, and is unlikely to be in summaries - and has returned with a vengeance for Season 4.  You'll be more confused than not for having skipped watching Season 1...

Comment: @DavRob60 But if you still don't want to watch it, at least read the good summaries on Fringepedia:  http://fringepedia.net/wiki/Season_1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From http://fringepedia.net/wiki/Gene

> Gene is the name given to the cow requested by Walter Bishop during
>   the reopening of his lab at Harvard University. It is unknown who
>   named the cow Gene, but Olivia is the first to use the name.
>
> Peter Bishop explains that since cows are genetically very similar to
>   humans, experiments on cows, simulate effects on humans; they are an
>   ethical test subject when using a human guinea-pig might be dangerous.

Comment: Also, the Appearances section does list Gene as having been in Season 1 several times

Comment: I thought Walter named the cow, but my memory on that point could be fuzzy.  I believe there was one particular episode in Season 1 where she was introduced.

Comment: Note that we've never seen Gene used for experiments, but we have seen her used for milk several times.

Comment: *Dr. Walter Bishop*: The only thing better than a cow is a human! Unless you need milk. Then you really need a cow.

Comment: @Iszi Yep, halfway through the very first episode (a two-parter, so around 40 minutes in), which is when Goran Jovic's quote is from.  Olivia says the name about 7 minutes later when Francis asks about it.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "Jean" rather than "Gene"?

Comment: @JoeL. "Gene" is a common informal version of "[Eugene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_(given_name))", and [makes sense for a mad scientist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene), so I think it's right.  I don't know what the script said, though.

Comment: @Izkata: In the U.S. both "Gene" and Eugene" are pretty exclusively *male* names, though.

Comment: @JoeL. - Since the point of having the cow is to take advantage of its genetic similarity to humans, "Gene" would be the obvious name. (Gene - genetic. Get it?)

Answer (score 4):

Walter asked for a cow in the pilot episode, "Pilot". It's unknown who named it Gene.

According to [the transcript at Fringepedia](https://web.archive.org/web/20170211113758/http://www.fringepedia.net/wiki/Pilot/Transcript#ACT_IV) (preserved by the Wayback Machine):

> ### ACT IV
>
> #### Harvard Lab - Setting Up
>
> OLIVIA: Dr. Bishop, I've ordered a standard forensics' work package. Is there anything else you need?
> WALTER: Optical coherence tomograph for flesh study. Two thousand pounds of silicon. At least five anonymous blood samples from volunteer donors, micro-organism detector. NASA grade, of course. There's still NASA, yes?
> OLIVIA: Yes.
> WALTER: Oh, she's still here. This tank was the best. And a two-Year-old bos taurus.
> ASTRID: A what?
> PETER: A cow. He wants a cow.
> WALTER: Purebred, not a crossbred, this is important. Mature weight 850 pounds, total fat average 2.37.
> OLIVIA: Is he joking?
> PETER: Genetically, humans and cows are separated by only a couple lines of DNA. So, what's an ethical test subject?
> OLIVIA: Where'd you learn that? MIT?
> PETER: No actually, I picked that up reading books. You should try it sometime. It's fun.
> OLIVIA: (to Astrid) Get him the cow.
> WALTER: Fantastic, thank you. Only thing better than a cow is a human. Unless you need milk. Then you really need a cow.
> (Activity including Walter examining laboratory slides; Olivia reviewing photos of Flight victims; an unidentified, and unrelated, class in session; and the arrival of the cow.)
>
> [...]
>
> #### Harvard Lab - John Scott Arrives
>
> [...]
> CHARLIE: Is that a cow?
> OLIVIA: Yeah, that's Gene.

Answer (score 2):

Peter thinks Walter wants the cow for a test subject in the pilot, but Walter never actually says that himself.  Walter actually mentions right then that you need a cow for milk, and we see Walter frequently drinking milk from the cow too.  The only experiment I remember Walter ever doing with the cow involved trying to get the cow to produce chocolate milk!

So I think, if we read between the lines, Walter probably just wanted a cow for fresh milk and was pulling a fast one on the FBI :)

Comment: I still find it unbelievable that he'd drink raw milk. He's a scientist, has he not heard of Pasteurisation?

Comment: @PointlessSpike We're talking about a guy who regularly takes all manner of recreational drugs in combination. I'm sure he wouldn't worry about unpasteurised milk.

Comment: @maguirenumber6- I think he only takes drugs that can be synthesized.