# Why is there a dinosaur in the Batcave?

Tags: dc, the-new-52, batman

In Batman #1 in the New 52, when we visit the Batcave for the first time, we see a dinosaur:

[image: full page]
[image: close up on the panel]

What... is up with that? It is a completely awesome cave decoration - but what else is it? Is it a non sequitur or is it a call back to an earlier storyline? I imagine it's the latter – a life-size T-rex model is an expensive piece of decor, even for Bruce Wayne.

Bonus points: are there any other relics from past storylines visible in this Batcave?

Update: here's a shot of the other panel that gives us a view of the "showroom" (including the huge dice).

[image: HOLY HUGE DICE, BATMAN]

Comment: The real question is, why WOULDN'T you have a have a dinosaur in a Batcave? [Who doesn't like fresh dinosaur eggs, laced with unmetabolized excess hallucinogens, with their coffee?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6864/why-there-is-a-cow-in-walter-bishops-lab)

Comment: That appears to be a show room. It's likely a model for scientific interest...though entirely out of place considering the other exhibits. I suppose the giant stone dice are a bit out of place too though. But Batman's an engineer, not an interior decorator.

Comment: @BenBrocka: The giant Joker card and humungous penny are interesting too.

Comment: @gnovice Hah, I hadn't seen the giant penny. That might be my favorite.

Comment: He often acts as a rich eccentric. You'd think the Joker card would be bad memories though, or maybe it's a trophy.

Comment: There's also what seems to be a giant question mark, presumably from the Riddler.

Comment: Why would you have a showroom in your SECRET batcave?

Comment: @JamesRyan To show off to the other superheroes.  It certainly impressed The Flash when he came to visit.

Comment: "a life-size T-rex model is an expensive piece of decor, even for Bruce Wayne" I disagree -- a **real** *T. Rex* skeleton is worth [less than $10 million](https://www.npr.org/2015/10/29/452763153/yes-you-can-put-a-price-on-a-t-rex), as it turns out. Meanwhile Bruce Wayne's fortune is usually pegged at [$6 to $9 billion](https://www.forbes.com/special-report/2013/fictional-15/bruce-wayne.html); as far as billionaire splurges go, a full dinosaur fossil is chump change.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batcave#Memorabilia):

> The cave stores unique memorabilia items collected from the various cases Batman has worked. Originally, these were stored in a room designed just for them; *it was explained that Batman and Robin took one memento from each case*. Later, the trophies were shown to be in the large main area of the cave, residing among the rest of the Batcave's furnishings.
>
> The most famous and prevalently featured are **a full-size animatronic Tyrannosaurus Rex**, a giant Lincoln penny, and an oversized Joker playing card. The **T. Rex comes from an adventure on "Dinosaur Island" (Batman #35, 1946);** the penny was originally a trophy from Batman's encounter with a penny-obsessed villain named the Penny Plunderer (World's Finest Comics #30, 1947). Other "keepsakes" in the cave come from "The Thousand and One Trophies of Batman!" (Detective Comics #158, 1950). These three stories were reprinted in Batman #256.
>
> Other pieces often shown in the Batcave are Two-Face's original coin, Deathstroke's sword (the owner of which Batman has fought at least twice), the shroud of the vampiric Monk, and over-sized ten-pins.

He has also had Fries' original freeze gun, a piece of kryptonite, and old partner costumes.

Comment: I think the Robin costume in the case is Jason Todd’s. So he keeps his dead partner’s costume in a case. Nice touch there, Bats. Nice touch.

Comment: There's something to be said for the interpretation that Batman (especially in his more recent iterations) is not a hero, rather he's a psychopath just like all the others; it just so happens that his eccentricities (refusal to kill, obsession with justice) make him easier to tolerate than other psychopaths.

Comment: Batman: TAS has an interesting twist on the origin of the giant penny - rather than coming from a penny-obsessed villian, it belonged to Two-Face, and was meant to be a death trap that Batman was strapped to and almost crushed by.

Comment: In the new 52, the penny was originally in front of Wayne Enterprises, then used again as a conductor for a signal jammer during Riddler's siege of the city.

Answer (score 31):

The T-Rex comes [Batman #35](http://www.comicvine.com/batman-dick-grayson-author/37-120799/) (June, 1946). 
"Batman and Robin are challenged to a game of "Touch Hunt" on famed Dinosaur Island in return for a gift to charity in the amount of $5000.....if they win the game. But they soon discover that they are the prey being hunted....by a very human adversary!" ([source](http://www.comics.org/issue/5170/))

Dinosaur Island was an amusement park filled with robotic dinosaurs.

Comment: They had to touch what now?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Continuity. [According to the DC Wiki](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batman%27s_T-Rex), in the original:

> It was a robot that Batman fought during an early adventure in Murray Wilson Hart's theme park on "Dinosaur Island"

in Batman Volume 1: issue 35.

In the DC animated Universe there are two depictions of the T-Rex. Again from the DC Wiki:

> Batman and Robin first came across the T-Rex after battling a lesser criminal. Robin thought it would make a good memento, but Batman stated that transporting it alone would attract unwanted attention. Nevertheless, he later relented to place it in the cave. As a visual nod to Batman battling an animatronic dinosaur, the episode "Mean Seasons" Calender Girl unleashes a Studio mechanical T-Rex to kill Batman, Batman subsequently destroys it.

Presumably keeping it as a memento.