# What are the other Batmobiles from the first edition of the New 52 Batman?

Tags: dc, batman, the-new-52

Looking at this question [Why is there a dinosaur in the Batcave?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8878/why-is-there-a-dinosaur-in-the-batcave) I noticed there are four Batmobiles in the Batcave.

The one on the top right looks like the Batmobile as seen in the 1989 Batman movie. I presume the most prominent is the current Batmobile. Are these other models taken from previous versions of the Batmobiles?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Almost as much an icon as the Batman himself, the Batmobile has seen as many transformations as the character has over the decades. Looking at several major compilations of Batmobiles through the ages, I was unable to match any but the two-finned model to the 2006 Batman: Under The Hood on the upper right side.

The smaller coup with the Batman Beyond logo is unfamiliar and does not even superficially resemble any known models I could find. The motorcycle looks like an adaptation of the vehicle seen in the recent Nolan movie versions of Batman with a bit of armor thrown over the frame.

I have a link to Batmobiles Through the Ages for anyone else to see if they can match the other vehicles. I believe many scene such as this one are thrown together without much thought to the vehicles unless the artist has a personal favorite beyond whatever Batmobile they are designing at the time.

The Batmobile History site lists these four vehicles as:

> After a fight at Arkham Asylum, Batman returns to the Batcave to try out some new equipment and prepare for an evening as Bruce Wayne. Artist Greg Capullo sets the scene with a broad view of the Cave, including several Batmobiles parked on a platform near the main exit tunnel. Among these are the [1989 movie car](http://www.batmobilehistory.com/1989-batmobile.php), the [flying Batmobile](http://www.batmobilehistory.com/2009br01-batmobile.php), and [this car](http://www.batmobilehistory.com/2011-batman-01a-batmobile.php) (as well as another new design on a lift). Capullo did not base this Batmobile on any pre-existing design, but rather freehanded it as a way to help fill out the scene.

The definitive site for Batmobile History can be found at: http://www.batmobilehistory.com. The site compiles the most popular models of Batmobiles and their collective histories.

[image]

Comment: I had the same idea to post the image :) Best to not have 2 of that insanely large image, so I removed mine.

Comment: Great minds think alike. :)

Comment: Conspicuous by its absence is the Batmobile from The Dark Knight Returns: http://www.batmobilehistory.com/miller-batmobile.php

Comment: Actually, I went through the Batmobile history images and quite a few are missing from this graphic. I think the people who commissioned it were looking for iconic vehicles that still resembled cars. But I could have done without some of the stranger ones to include the Dark Knight's tank-mobile.

Comment: That little car with the red symbol kinda looks like the 2009 submersible from Batman Reborn: The Domino Effect that appears in your larger image.

Comment: Though its drawn underwater, I am to understand it was a flying vehicle. I found it in the Batmobile History site as a flying car, see notes above. (There's no reason it couldn't have been submersible as well, of course.)